# Generate permalinks

Tags: functions, permalinks

I want the permalinks to be like youtube generated from letters and numbers in 9 digits I modified this code

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'unique_slug_108286', 10, 4 );
function unique_slug_108286( $slug) { 
    $n=4;
    $slug = bin2hex(random_bytes($n));  //just an example
    return $slug;
}
```

so it's worked and gave me a random slug , but the problem is that this slug is changed every time I entered the post at the backend , so I need it to be generated once and unique

I also found this solution it also worked but the same problem It's changed every time I enter the post

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'unique_slug_so_11762070', 10, 6 );

function unique_slug_so_11762070( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
    $new_slug = so_11762070_unique_post_slug('guid');
    return $new_slug;
}

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762698
function so_11762070_unique_post_slug($col,$table='wp_posts'){
     global $wpdb;

     $alphabet = array_merge( range(0, 9), range('a','z') );

     $already_exists = true;
     do {

         $guidchr = array();
         for ($i=0; $i<32; $i++)
         $guidchr[] = $alphabet[array_rand( $alphabet )];


         $guid = sprintf( "%s", implode("", array_slice($guidchr, 0, 12, true)) );

       // check that GUID is unique
       $already_exists = (boolean) $wpdb->get_var("
       SELECT COUNT($col) as the_amount FROM $table WHERE $col = '$guid'
       ");

      } while (true == $already_exists);

     return $guid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `wp_unique_post_slug` filter is post id. You can utilize that to generate the slug only once while creating the post for the first time.

**Method 1:**

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'unique_slug_108286', 10, 2 );
function unique_slug_108286( $slug, $postId ) {
    if ( ! $postId ) {
        $n = 4;
        $slug = bin2hex( random_bytes( $n ) );  //just an example
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

*Other method would be using post meta to indicate whether a slug has been generated.*

**Method 2:**

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'unique_slug_108286', 10, 2 );
function unique_slug_108286( $slug, $postId ) {
    if ( $postId && ! get_post_meta( $postId, 'slug_generated', true ) ) {
        $n = 4;
        $slug = bin2hex( random_bytes( $n ) );  //just an example
        update_post_meta( $postId, 'slug_generated', true );
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: thank you , but it may I didn't got you , I replace this code with the one I got , but the first slug of the post which is the post title is not changing , so there is no new slug generation

Comment: @Akel in that case, i have added a 2nd method. The first method will work if you are using `wp_insert_post` function to create post, second method will work when creating the post through backend.

Comment: I really Aprciate your help but unfortunetly it's not working with me :( 
I just add the second method to function.php and set the permalinks option to /%postname%/ but nothing changed

Comment: it's worked first when I finish writing the post title it generates a permalinks as well , but after publishing the post it's taking the title name as a permalink

Comment: There might be other factor on your wp setup. I had tested this on a fresh wp installation, worked as expected.

Comment: It's my bad luck then :( 
Thank you anyway very much and I hope if you have time so you could help me more 
I can contact you if you like :(
thank you alot once more

Comment: when I remove this line         update_post_meta( $postId, 'slug_generated', true ); 
the slug is regenerated in every update but when I put it , it took a random slug first and after publishing the post the slug took the post title

Comment: Although OP didn't mark this as accepted, this is a really good answer. Both approaches are great, especially using `post_meta`.

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I found the solution

```
function append_slug($data) {
    global $post_ID;

    if (empty($data['post_name'])) {
        $n=4;
        $data['post_name'] = bin2hex(random_bytes($n));
    }

    return $data;
}
```

thank you all for help